# What does Kernel of the natural map mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

> Let $G$ be a topological group and let $H$ be a normal subgroup.  Prove that $G/H$ is a topological group, where $G/H$ is regarded as the quotient space of $G$ by the kernel of the natural map.

What does "by the kernel of the natural map" mean?

I understand that the natural map is a map from a space to its quotient space mapping points to their equivalence classes, but I don't understand what they mean by kernel of the natural map since it's talking about a topological space.

I understand "$G/H$ is a quotient space of $G$".  This means the natural map $v: G \rightarrow G/H$ through some partition or equivalence relation that results in the space $G/H$.

Comment: If you forget about the topology and just think about everything as groups. Can you then understand the statement?

Comment: @An.Ditlev No, I don't understand what it's asking here.  I know what a quotient space is and what it means to prove that a group is a topological group but I don't understand what kernel of the natural map means.  Is there a specific notation that that phrase can be rewritten as?

Comment: You can solve the exercise just by understanding the part before the last statement. 


Let G be a topological group and let H be a normal subgroup. Prove that G/H is a topological group. The last part is just to clarify what is meant by G/H.


The kernel of the natural map is everything in G, which is mapped to the equivalence class of the trivial element in G/H.

Comment: @An.Ditlev You're saying the kernel of the natural map is defined by everything in $G$.  So if $v$ is the natural map from $G \rightarrow G_i$ as a partition of the set then $\text{kernel}(v) = G$?

Comment: You have a map $G \to G/H$. now an element $g \in G$ is an element of the kernel if and only if $[ g] = [e] \in G/H$.

Comment: @An.Ditlev If $f : G \rightarrow G/H$ is a map from the topological space $G$ to the topological quotient space $G/H$, then what function is the natural map?

Comment: @An.Ditlev If we take $f$ to be the natural map, and we have the phrase "kernel of the natural map", what does it mean to take the kernel of a natural map that is a topological map?  What is $\text{kernel}(f)$?

Comment: I think you misread An.Ditlev's response about what the kernel is.  "The kernel of the natural map is the ... [set of elements in G which are]  ... mapped to the equivalence class of the trivial element in G/H."

Comment: The kernel of a map is exactly the set of elements that the map "misses" in the sense that every element in the kernel is mapped to the equivalence class of the identity/trivial element. Eg. In an additive group, the kernel is the set of elements mapped to [0] the equivalence class of 0.

Comment: @mathfan27543 I understand what a kernel is in terms of a map between two groups:  If $f : G \rightarrow K$ are two groups, then $\ker f = \{ x \in G : f(x) = \text{identity}_K\}$.  So your saying the kernel of the natural map $\text{kernel}(v)$, where $v$ is a map between two topological spaces $G$ and $G/H$ and not groups, has the same definition?

Comment: @Oliver The point here is that $G$ is both a topological space AND a group and you use the group structure to define the elements in the kernel of your map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A priori, the notation $G/H$ could mean two different things in this context:

- (Topological spaces) $G/H$ is the space obtained from $G$ by collapsing all of $H$ to a point (i.e., as a set, quotient of $G$ by the equivalence relation generated by $h \sim h'$ for all $h,h' \in H$);
- (Groups) $G/H$ is the group of left cosets $gH$ (i.e., as a set, quotient of $G$ by the equivalence relation $g \sim g' \iff g^{-1}g' \in H$).

If $G$ is a topological group and $H$ a normal subgroup, then $G/H$ is always to be interpreted in the sense of *groups* (second bullet point). I think the phrasing of the author meant to indicate that: $G/H$ is an *algebraic* (group-theoretic) quotient, namely, it is the quotient of $G$ by the kernel $H$ of the canonical projection map $G \to G/H$ that sends an element to its coset.